# Working with Xpath in android

Tags: java, android, xml

In the past ive used xpath to find the value of specific nodes that came from an xml ducemnt from a URL. Now i want to use this same code but from an xml document that is stored locally on the android phone at say `sdcard/images/xml/newxml.xml`
Here is the old code that i would like to be able to implement to use this, i just cannot figure out how to use the local xml file instead of a URL.

```
URL url = new URL("UrlWentHere");
InputSource xml = new InputSource(url.openStream());
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
datafromxml = xpath.evaluate("//forecast_conditions[1]/high/@data", xml);
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Why not just `URL url = new URL("sdcard/images/xml/newxml.xml");` - or does the problem have to do with the app's restricted access to the file system?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot and saw the word "URL" and assumed it had to be an URL/webaddress. wow. Im going to try that now, post this as an answer so i can give you credit! Thank you so much i really appreciate even though i feel so stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question. Why not just URL url = new URL("sdcard/images/xml/newxml.xml"); - or does the problem have to do with the app's restricted access to the file system?

Comment: Actually, to be precise, I guess the URL should really be `file://sdcard/images/xml/newxml.xml`, and an external one could e.g. be `http://www.whatever.com`. You may want to try that; it will make the distinction more explicit, and I think the URL isn't *really* valid otherwise. On the other hand, there is such a thing as a relative URL. Not sure if yours is actually relative, though.